# Adding Icons on top of edges in graphviz

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphviz, diagram, diagramming

Im trying to use graphviz to mimic the AWS Diagram scheme below:

[image: AWS Diagram]

I wanted to know if its possible to add icons on top of an edge, just like the following icons in the diagram :

AWS "Cloud"
VPC "Cloud"
Lock icon
Router icon
Internet Gateway Icon

Thank you